# NVDA spells words, where it shouldn't

Tags: html, accessibility, nvda

it seems that NVDA on Windows Chrome and FF doesn't read the word "selection" correctly. The word actually gets spelled. Setting the lang attribute doesn't help. I've tested this behavior also on other sites, like [This One](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-screen-reader-to-select-and-read-text-boxes-and-images-in-word-9c5bf5ca-9c24-41d0-ba68-8972caf95e88#PickTab=Windows) and get the same result: the word is spelled not read out.

When i tab to the buttons it says. "remove s e l e c t i o n". Do you have any ideas?

```html
<div lang="en">
  <button>
    remove selection
  </button>
  <button>
    add to selection
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a problem with NVDA itself. I tested on Win/Chrome using the link you provided, and NVDA does not read the word "selection" any differently from other words.  Entries in your "Voice Dictionary" (preferences > speech dictionaries > default | voice | temporary) may cause this. I'd start by looking there.

Comment: Tested here with latest NVDA and Chrome and the word "selection" is read normally. It looks like it's whether a configuration problem on your side, or a synthesizer or voice specific bug. What are you using for synthesizer, voice and language ? Does it change something if you use something else ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the entries in these three categories are empty. My system language is German, but since NVDA should work also with lang-attributes I am not considering it a problem.

But I changed the voice and it works now. But these voices, that don't spell out the word, have trouble with German pronunciation.

Comment: At least now you know that this is a voice specific bug. Sadly there isn't much to do.

Comment: Note that NVDA can switch accents and dialects (depending on the synthesizer you use) when it encounters a `lang` that is different from the page default but you have to install the different language packs in the Windows Narrator settings.  (NVDA uses the Narrator settings). Use Ctrl+WindowsLogo+N to bring up Narrator settings and select "Add more voices" then scroll to the bottom to add voices. I use the "Windows OneCore Voices" synthesizer for NVDA and it honors the `lang` setting and changes the voice. That might help get "selection" read as a real word.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your NVDA configuration has either been set to spell out certain words in its punctuation settings or, more likely, because it doesn't recognise the word as part of the system's default language (which you mention is German) and so it spells out any words it doesn't recognise.